# Export private key from X509Certificate object

Tags: c#, certificate, base64, private-key, x509certificate2

We use C# code we build X509Certificate2 with .p12 file, in the constructor we insert the path to certificate, certificate's password. We also marked it as Exportable as shown below:

```
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2
("...\\MyCerificate.p12", "P@ssw0rd", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

we get the private key as AsymmetricAlgorithm format by the following:

```
x509Certificate2.PrivateKey
```

Now, we want to get the private key from the certificate as *Base64* format - but we don't have any idea how to do it, and its so important for us.

Comment: What are you trying to use the Base64 output with? Is it a strict need or a preference?

Answer (score 6):

The important question is why **base64** ?

If this is for your own application then you can keep the private key as an XML string (much easier :-).

```
string xml = x509Certificate2.PrivateKey.ToXmlString (true);
```

If you want **base64** (again just for your application) you can export the key (RSAParameters) then concat every `byte[]` and turn the merged output to a base64 string.

But if you want to interop with other applications that requires a **base64** private key then you need to know the format (inside the **base64** string). E.g. in many case private keys are [PEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Privacy-enhanced_mail) encoded (which is base64 with a special header/footer, see an [example](http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/20040812-0816.html) for `X509Certificate`).

If that what's you're looking for then you'll need to encode the private key within a [PKCS#8](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2130) structure first, then turn in into base64 and add the header/footer. You can find some helpful code to do so [inside](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Cryptography/PKCS8.cs) Mono.Security.dll (MIT.X11 licensed code from the Mono project).

Comment: I depented on other application that requires to get base64 private key. I want to allow the user to insert X509Certificate2 and by myself extract the private key as base 64 format - do you know if .Net framework expose any way to do it?

Comment: NO, if it did (I really doubt that) or if I knew I would have included it in my answer. That being said your problem remains, it's not a **base64** issue, it's knowing that's **inside** that is important to interop with your other application.

Comment: The PKCS#8 link seams to be dead, I expected an article there but I only get an overview of RSA Labs' projects

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the PrivateKey property of X509Certificate2. 
The actual returned private key implementation depends on the algorithm used in the certificate - usually this is RSA:

```
rsaObj = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCertificate.PrivateKey;
```

Afterwards you should be able to get the RSA key information from it's ExportParameters property.

Comment: and when we know thw key information(for example RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx), how can we convert the private key to base64?

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with OpenSSL Library for .NET:

```
using DidiSoft.OpenSsl;
...
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2
("...\\MyCerificate.p12", "P@ssw0rd", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

PrivateKey privKey = PrivateKey.Load(x509Certificate2.PrivateKey);
bool withNewLines = true;
string base64PrivateKey = privKey.ToBase64String(withNewLines);
```

Answer (score -4):

If your only problem is to get the private key Base64 encoded, you can simply do like this:

```
var privateKey = x509Certificate2.PrivateKey;
var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(encoding.GetBytes(privateKey.ToString()));
```

Comment: privateKey.ToString() returns the "System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoserviceProvider".....,  this is not the private key...

Comment: @RRR is correct. You will find that x509Certificate2.PublicKey.Key.ToString() will return the *same* value doing it this way. That can't be right :)